# Creating new app with rails trying to connect postgresql- error occurred while installing pg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to create a rails app with postgres and I keep going in circles getting the same errors. I've been scouring the internet for the past two days trying everything and cannot get it to work. Can someone please help me figure this out? I am brand new to rails and new to coding in general.

Here is me first trying to create the app with postgresql as the database:

```
(base) Queen@MacBook-Air rails % rails new testing --database=postgresql
      create  
      create  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      create  .ruby-version
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  .gitattributes
      create  Gemfile
         run  git init from "."
hint: Using 'master' as the name for the initial branch. This default branch name
hint: is subject to change. To configure the initial branch name to use in all
hint: of your new repositories, which will suppress this warning, call:
hint: 
hint:   git config --global init.defaultBranch <name>
hint: 
hint: Names commonly chosen instead of 'master' are 'main', 'trunk' and
hint: 'development'. The just-created branch can be renamed via this command:
hint: 
hint:   git branch -m <name>
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/Queen/Documents/rails/testing/.git/
...
      remove  config/initializers/cors.rb
      remove  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_7_0.rb
         run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 13.0.6
Using racc 1.6.0
Using crass 1.0.6
Using minitest 5.15.0
Using builder 3.2.4
Using digest 3.1.0
Using timeout 0.2.0
Using strscan 3.0.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.10
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.5
Using marcel 1.0.2
Using bundler 2.3.11
Using erubi 1.10.0
Using rack 2.2.3
Using nio4r 2.5.8
Using io-console 0.5.11
Using bindex 0.8.1
Using msgpack 1.5.1
Using mini_mime 1.1.2
Using matrix 0.4.2
Using rexml 3.2.5
Using rubyzip 2.3.2
Using nokogiri 1.13.4 (arm64-darwin)
Using net-protocol 0.1.3
Using i18n 1.10.0
Using tzinfo 2.0.4
Fetching pg 1.3.5
Using childprocess 4.1.0
Using rack-test 1.1.0
Using sprockets 4.0.3
Using public_suffix 4.0.7
Using puma 5.6.4
Using method_source 1.0.0
Using loofah 2.16.0
Using mail 2.7.1
Using net-imap 0.2.3
Using websocket-driver 0.7.5
Using zeitwerk 2.5.4
Using net-smtp 0.3.1
Using bootsnap 1.11.1
Using thor 1.2.1
Using selenium-webdriver 4.1.0
Using regexp_parser 2.3.0
Using addressable 2.8.0
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.4.2
Using activesupport 7.0.2.3
Using net-pop 0.1.1
Using webdrivers 5.0.0
Using xpath 3.2.0
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using capybara 3.36.0
Using activemodel 7.0.2.3
Using globalid 1.0.0
Using actionview 7.0.2.3
Using reline 0.3.1
Using activejob 7.0.2.3
Using actionpack 7.0.2.3
Using irb 1.4.1
Using jbuilder 2.11.5
Using sprockets-rails 3.4.2
Using actioncable 7.0.2.3
Using activerecord 7.0.2.3
Using actionmailer 7.0.2.3
Using railties 7.0.2.3
Using debug 1.5.0
Using activestorage 7.0.2.3
Using importmap-rails 1.0.3
Using stimulus-rails 1.0.4
Using actionmailbox 7.0.2.3
Using web-console 4.2.0
Using actiontext 7.0.2.3
Using turbo-rails 1.0.1
Using rails 7.0.2.3
Installing pg 1.3.5 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/pg-1.3.5/ext
/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/bin/ruby -I
/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0 -r
./siteconf20220418-88114-drsbsc.rb extconf.rb
Calling libpq with GVL unlocked
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/local/bin/pg_config
checking for whether -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib is accepted as LDFLAGS... yes
Using libpq from /usr/local/lib
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*****************************************************************************

Unable to find PostgreSQL client library.

Please install libpq or postgresql client package like so:
  brew install libpq

or try again with:
  gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config

or set library paths manually with:
gem install pg -- --with-pg-include=/path/to/libpq-fe.h/
--with-pg-lib=/path/to/libpq.so/

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
 ...

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/extensions/arm64-darwin-21/3.1.0/pg-1.3.5/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

...
An error occurred while installing pg (1.3.5), and Bundler cannot
continue.

In Gemfile:
  pg
         run  bundle binstubs bundler
Could not find gem 'pg (~> 1.1)' in locally installed gems.
       rails  importmap:install
Could not find gem 'pg (~> 1.1)' in locally installed gems.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
       rails  turbo:install stimulus:install
Could not find gem 'pg (~> 1.1)' in locally installed gems.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I then tried to do what it said with gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config. Here is what happened:

```
(base) Queen@MacBook-Air ~ % ls /usr/local/bin         
2to3            jest            pg_restore
2to3-3.7        msgattrib       pg_rewind
acountry        msgcat          pg_test_fsync
adig            msgcmp          pg_test_timing
ahost           msgcomm         pg_upgrade
autoconf        msgconv         pg_verifybackup
autoheader      msgen           pg_waldump
autom4te        msgexec         pgbench
autopoint       msgfilter       pip3
autoreconf      msgfmt          pip3.7
autoscan        msggrep         pkg-config
autoupdate      msginit         postgres
brew            msgmerge        postmaster
brotli          msgunfmt        psql
clusterdb       msguniq         pydoc3
createdb        ngettext        pydoc3.7
createuser      nodemon         python3
dropdb          npm         python3-config
dropuser        npx         python3.7
easy_install-3.7    oid2name        python3.7-config
ecpg            pcre2-config        python3.7m
envsubst        pcre2grep       python3.7m-config
gettext         pcre2test       pyvenv
gettext.sh      pg_amcheck      pyvenv-3.7
gettextize      pg_archivecleanup   rbenv
git         pg_basebackup       rbenv-install
git-cvsserver       pg_checksums        rbenv-uninstall
git-receive-pack    pg_config       recode-sr-latin
git-shell       pg_controldata      reindexdb
git-upload-archive  pg_ctl          ruby-build
git-upload-pack     pg_dump         surge
heroku          pg_dumpall      vacuumdb
idle3           pg_isready      vacuumlo
idle3.7         pg_receivewal       xgettext
ifnames         pg_recvlogical      yarn
initdb          pg_resetwal     yarnpkg
(base) Queen@MacBook-Air ~ % gem install pg --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    invalid option: --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
(base) Queen@MacBook-Air ~ % gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
Building native extensions with: '--with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/pg-1.3.5/ext
/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/bin/ruby -I /Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0 -r ./siteconf20220418-90925-oiasjs.rb extconf.rb --with-pg-config\=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
Calling libpq with GVL unlocked
Using config values from /usr/local/bin/pg_config
checking for whether -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib is accepted as LDFLAGS... yes
Using libpq from /usr/local/lib
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*****************************************************************************

Unable to find PostgreSQL client library.

Please install libpq or postgresql client package like so:
  brew install libpq

or try again with:
  gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config

or set library paths manually with:
  gem install pg -- --with-pg-include=/path/to/libpq-fe.h/ --with-pg-lib=/path/to/libpq.so/

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

...

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/extensions/arm64-darwin-21/3.1.0/pg-1.3.5/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/pg-1.3.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/extensions/arm64-darwin-21/3.1.0/pg-1.3.5/gem_make.out
```

I then opened up the log where it said to check why it failed and got this:

```
block in append_ldflags: checking for whether -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib is accepted as LDFLAGS... -------------------- yes

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib "clang -o 
...

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib "clang -o conftest -I/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/include/ruby-3.1.0/arm64-darwin21 -I/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/include/ruby-3.1.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/include/ruby-3.1.0 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/include  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -fdeclspec -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens -Wundef  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L. -L/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib  -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib     -lruby.3.1 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return !!argv[argc];
6: }
/* end */

--------------------

find_header: checking for libpq-fe.h... -------------------- yes

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib "clang -
...

--------------------

find_header: checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... -------------------- yes

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib "clang -
...

--------------------

find_header: checking for pg_config_manual.h... -------------------- yes

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib "clang -I/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/include/ruby-3.1.0/arm64-darwin21 -
...

--------------------

have_library: checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... -------------------- no

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib "clang -o conftest -I/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/include/ruby-3.1.0/arm64-darwin21 -I/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/include/ruby-3.1.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/include/ruby-3.1.0 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/include  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -fdeclspec -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens -Wundef  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L. -L/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib  -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib     -lruby.3.1 -lpq   "
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libpq.dylib, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_PQconnectdb", referenced from:
      _t in conftest-1d6349.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 8: {
 9:   if (argc > 1000000) {
10:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
11:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
12:   }
13: 
14:   return !!argv[argc];
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))PQconnectdb; return !p; }
/* end */

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib "clang -o conftest -I/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/include/ruby-3.1.0/arm64-darwin21 -I/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/include/ruby-3.1.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/include/ruby-3.1.0 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/include  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -fdeclspec -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens -Wundef  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L. -L/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib  -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib     -lruby.3.1 -lpq   "
conftest.c:16:13: error: conflicting types for 'PQconnectdb'
extern void PQconnectdb();
            ^
/usr/local/include/libpq-fe.h:285:16: note: previous declaration is here
extern PGconn *PQconnectdb(const char *conninfo);
               ^
conftest.c:17:27: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'conninfo' was not specified
int t(void) { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
              ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/libpq-fe.h:285:16: note: 'PQconnectdb' declared here
extern PGconn *PQconnectdb(const char *conninfo);
               ^
2 errors generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 8: {
 9:   if (argc > 1000000) {
10:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
11:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
12:   }
13: 
14:   return !!argv[argc];
15: }
16: extern void PQconnectdb();
17: int t(void) { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... -------------------- no

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib "clang -o conftest -I/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/include/ruby-3.1.0/arm64-darwin21 -I/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/include/ruby-3.1.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/include/ruby-3.1.0 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/include  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -fdeclspec -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens -Wundef  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L. -L/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib  -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib     -lruby.3.1 -llibpq   "
ld: library not found for -llibpq
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 8: {
 9:   if (argc > 1000000) {
10:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
11:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
12:   }
13: 
14:   return !!argv[argc];
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))PQconnectdb; return !p; }
/* end */

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib "clang -o conftest -I/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/include/ruby-3.1.0/arm64-darwin21 -I/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/include/ruby-3.1.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/include/ruby-3.1.0 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/include  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -fdeclspec -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens -Wundef  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L. -L/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib  -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib     -lruby.3.1 -llibpq   "
conftest.c:16:13: error: conflicting types for 'PQconnectdb'
extern void PQconnectdb();
            ^
/usr/local/include/libpq-fe.h:285:16: note: previous declaration is here
extern PGconn *PQconnectdb(const char *conninfo);
               ^
conftest.c:17:27: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'conninfo' was not specified
int t(void) { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
              ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/libpq-fe.h:285:16: note: 'PQconnectdb' declared here
extern PGconn *PQconnectdb(const char *conninfo);
               ^
2 errors generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 8: {
 9:   if (argc > 1000000) {
10:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
11:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
12:   }
13: 
14:   return !!argv[argc];
15: }
16: extern void PQconnectdb();
17: int t(void) { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... -------------------- no

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib "clang -o conftest -I/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/include/ruby-3.1.0/arm64-darwin21 -I/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/include/ruby-3.1.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/include/ruby-3.1.0 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/include  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -fdeclspec -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens -Wundef  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L. -L/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib  -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib     -lruby.3.1 -lms/libpq   "
ld: library not found for -lms/libpq
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 8: {
 9:   if (argc > 1000000) {
10:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
11:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
12:   }
13: 
14:   return !!argv[argc];
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))PQconnectdb; return !p; }
/* end */

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib "clang -o conftest -I/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/include/ruby-3.1.0/arm64-darwin21 -I/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/include/ruby-3.1.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/include/ruby-3.1.0 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/include  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -fdeclspec -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens -Wundef  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L. -L/Users/Queen/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib  -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib     -lruby.3.1 -lms/libpq   "
conftest.c:16:13: error: conflicting types for 'PQconnectdb'
extern void PQconnectdb();
            ^
/usr/local/include/libpq-fe.h:285:16: note: previous declaration is here
extern PGconn *PQconnectdb(const char *conninfo);
               ^
conftest.c:17:27: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'conninfo' was not specified
int t(void) { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
              ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/libpq-fe.h:285:16: note: 'PQconnectdb' declared here
extern PGconn *PQconnectdb(const char *conninfo);
               ^
2 errors generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 8: {
 9:   if (argc > 1000000) {
10:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
11:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
12:   }
13: 
14:   return !!argv[argc];
15: }
16: extern void PQconnectdb();
17: int t(void) { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
/* end */
```

I'm lost. I've tried brew update, brew install postgresql, gem install pg and brew install libpq. Please help. I used a mac install guide for ruby on rails located here: https://mac.install.guide/rubyonrails/12.html
I have an M1 Macbook Air running on MacOS Monterey Version 12.3.1

Comment: can you try with `gem install pg -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"`

Comment: @theabhisheksoni it failed with same error

Comment: Did you try the ready made [Postgres.app binary](https://postgresapp.com/) instead of installing it though homebrew? I haven't used OS-X in a while but remeber it as being just click and go. Installing PG via home/linuxbrew on the other hand never really worked out. Last time I tried I ended up just using apt-get instead.

Comment: @max I actually already had Postgres app on my computer and had been using it with express and flask with no issue.